# How to convert MP3 to wav with external libraries or SDK Android?

Tags: android, file-conversion, transcoding

I need to convert an MP3 audio file in wav format using java libraries or Android SDK. 
I tried:

- JMF Java frameworks and official SOUND library: it is not possible in Android to compile this library because it is older than the Java compiler requested by the Android operating system
- JLAYER 1.0.1 Java library code: it works but the performance is embarrassing, 8 minutes for the conversion of audio files
- LAME Project written in C code: I configured the environment to handle Both Java and C code (NDK), but when I run the code It does not convert the files even if you do not get errors
- GStreamer Project written in C code: It Is not clear how to use this library with Android, Is there any complete example?

Let me know if there are other solutions